# What affect longitudinal conductance but not hall conductance in semiconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, scattering, quantum-hall-effect

Hi as a general question, what mechanisms (e.g. impurities) affect σxx but not as much σxy in a semiconductor system at low temperature with impurities.

I know with electric field scattering induced displacement of cyclotron center moves on average parallel to the electric field direction, but does anyone know any other mechanisms under vertical magnetic field that can affect transverse conductivity but not the hall conductivity?

Thank you.

Comment: well that would be every mechanism that effects resistance in general, phonons, dislocations etc.

Comment: Yes! we would like to know all the contributions that is related friend.

Comment: ok so they would be, density of states, temperature, pressure, impurities(that can be in two ways, external dopings or lattice dislocations), also external magnetic field has a minor effect on resistivity(magnetic break down), strains, bending, basically any creative way you can think that alter the perfect periodicty of the metal(perfectly periodic metal has zero resistance but this is impossible even temperature alters periodicty), slab size and shape, also chemical reactivity of slab with the medium it is in (air generally), and lattice interactions

Comment: that is electron electron interaction, electron phonon and phonon phonon interaction

Comment: finally if you want comprehensive  explanation of all of this just read https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4899-5717-7